# LINQ Filtered List using Exact Word

Tags: c#, linq

I have this list of string. I want to filter out only those items that have exact match to my searched keyword. For example I have keyword "in" I want the result to filter only those item that have exact word "in". Please help.

**Code**

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetData()
       {
           var strList = new List<string> 
           { "I'm in love",
            "Coffee contains caffeine",
            "The best inn so far",
            "Inside of me",
            "in the darkness"};
           var filteredItems = strList.Where(x => x.Contains("in"));
           return filteredItems;
       }
```

From my list I want to return item 1 and item 5 only since they are the items that have exact word "in".

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var filteredItems = strList.Where(x => (" " + x + " ").Contains(" in "));
```

or this:

```
var filteredItems = strList.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, "(^| )in($| )"));
```

Case insensitive versions:

```
var filteredItems = strList.Where(x => (" " + x .ToLower() + " ").Contains(" in "));
var filteredItems = strList.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, "(^|\s)in($|\s)",
                                                     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

Comment: The opposite of out is in.

Comment: expression cannot contain lambda expressions , and other options are not working in case of match 0 in image_0.jpg

Comment: @StavBodik I have no idea how to help you based on that information. If you have code that's not working, feel free to create a new question.

Comment: @StavBodik If you can't figure out how to use my answer correctly, then show your code so I or somebody else can help you. Don't just downvote and leave a complaint that provides 0 useful information.

Comment: exact match with Regex not works with LINQ queries you cannot contain lambda expressions with in it. your other solutions wont answer the problem of exact match in string because for example you want to find file in folder of images where x is the number of image : image_x.jpg...so if u look for matching "0" with contains for  image_10.jpg will result true .

Comment: But on the other hand now I realize thanks to you that I should use contains("_x.") and your answer is helpful, Accept my apology, please.

Comment: @StavBodik  
I'm still not sure what you're talking about, but my answer addresses OP's requirements. I still don't understand why you took issue with my answer for not handling your separate set of requirements. I'm not clairvoyant and I didn't know that you would come along one day and expect my answer to solve a problem that OP didn't describe. Try to be a bit more prudent with that downvote button, ay?

Answer (score 2):

I would look to use the [Regex.IsMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx) method. For example:

```
string pattern = "<your pattern here>";

static IEnumerable<string> GetData()
   {
       var strList = new List<string> 
       { "I'm in love",
        "Coffee contains caffeine",
        "The best inn so far",
        "Inside of me",
        "in the darkness"};
       var filteredItems = strList.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, pattern));
       return filteredItems;
   }
```

A pattern which should match is: `^(.*)\sin\s(.*)$`

So zero or more characters, then " in " (i.e. surrounded by whitespace) then zero or more characters. You could use something like [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) or the many other things like that on the net to test your Regex with your strings to make sure you're getting the right mileage :-)

Slightly tongue in cheek, but Regex might give you more [problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html) :-)

HTH, Nathan

Answer (score 1):

Right way to do it is to construct a regex.

Cheap way to do it, add spaces to the front and back of strings-to-match-against, match for the word you're looking for with spaces in the front and back:

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetData(string match)
   {
       var strList = new List<string> 
       { "I'm in love",
        "Coffee contains caffeine",
        "The best inn so far",
        "Inside of me",
        "in the darkness"};

       match = match.ToLower(); //to do case insensitive matching
       var filteredItems = strList.Where(x => (" " +x.ToLower() + " ").Contains(" "+match+" "));
       return filteredItems;
   }
```